# Azure MongoDB + Synapse Link: Column values unexpectedly contain JSON

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-cosmos-db-analytical-store?tabs=openrowset-credential) and have created an Azure MongoDB (Mongo API) and a Synapse Workspace, imported the ECDC data into MongoDB and connected it in Synapse Workspace. So far so good.
However, when I query the data, for e.g. string column date_rep I get
`{"string":"2020-12-14"}` instead of just `2020-12-14`

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=analytcstest;Database=ecdc',
                OBJECT = 'ecds',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'analytcstest'
)  with ( date_rep varchar(200) ) as rows
```

When don't specify the "with" clause to automatically infer the schema, I have the same problem:

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=analytcstest;Database=ecdc',
                OBJECT = 'ecds',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'analytcstest'
)  as rows
```

[image: screenshot query]

I could parse it of course, like this, but I don't understand why I have to do that and it's not in the docs?

```
SELECT TOP 10 JSON_VALUE([date_rep], '$.string') AS [date_rep]
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=analytcstest;Database=ecdc',
                OBJECT = 'ecds',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'analytcstest'
)  with ( date_rep varchar(200) ) as rows
```

Comment: This can be because you are using API for mongo db Because I tried with both SQL API and Mongo Db API When I used SQL API I got output values without json With Mongo Dbgetting it with json can be because of **The Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB stores data in a document structure, via BSON format.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reproduce similar thing in my environment and getting similar output A value with data type when I used the CosmosDB for Mongo API:

[image]

this can be because of the **The Azure Cosmos DB API for MongoDB stores data in a document structure, via BSON format.** It is a bin­ary-en­coded seri­al­iz­a­tion of JSON documents. BSON has been extended to add some optional non-JSON-native data types, like dates and binary data.

The `Cosmos DB API for MongoDB` is meant for MongoDB experience and continue to use your favorite MongoDB drivers, SDKs, and tools by pointing your application to the API for MongoDB account's connection string.

When I tried similar thing with the `CosmosDB for SQL API`  it stores data in Json format, and it is giving appropriate result for that.

[image]

For more information on BSON refer this [Document](https://www.mongodb.com/basics/bson)

Comment: Thanks! Will just have to parse the JSON then :)

Comment: Hello @Boland, In the example you have cited, do you have nested JSON ? For some reason, Synapse is restricting the output to root level elements from my Mong container. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: @Sau001 I have nested JSON and it works fine. Perhaps raise a request with MS?